# Whole Page Background Slides (width and height) with Owl Carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am attempting to get something [like this](http://www.cssigniter.com/preview/hugo) done but using Owl Carousel.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="home-slider">
        <div class="slide-0">
            Slider 0
        </div><!-- .slide-0 -->
        <div class="slide-1">
            Slider 1
        </div><!-- .slide-1 -->
        <div class="slide-2">
            Slider 2
        </div><!-- .slide-2 -->
    </div><!-- .home-slider -->
</body>
```

**SCSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.home-slider {
    .slide-0 {
        background: url('../img/Man-1920x1000.jpg') no-repeat 0px 0px transparent;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.home-slider').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    autoHeight: true
  });
});
```

That isn't working at all, I'm just getting a thin strip at the top of the page. I can go and make every single element leading up to the slide `<div` a height of `100%` but surely that isn't the smart thing to do.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zWbqV/59/

Comment: Thanks @MohdAbdulMujib but that [doesn't seem to work](http://nativeleaf.co.uk/static/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont want the whole page to slide, you want the background to slide.
you want to setup a section or div for carousel and z-index it to -10 or z-index your main content to 10 and creat the carousel in the first div. like that only background slides and not the whole page. you dont want your nav to slide away!

Also, by choosing a large image you can set it to width:100% so it resizes according to window size. defining the height to 100% as well as width will deform the image.

and z-index the carousel buttons to 100 in the very buttom of the page.

```
<body>

<div style="z-index:10">
    //your page content goes here including Nav
</div>
<div style="z-index:0 margin-top:0; TOP:0; POSITION:FIXED">
   //carousel code
</div>
//put button here OR
<div style="z-index:100" >
   // buttons
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: It hard to understand what you mean, do you mean similar to the JSFiddle Mohd gave in the comments? That [isn't working for me](http://nativeleaf.co.uk/static/index.html).

Comment: nope. go to the example site you posted. the hugo website. if you inspect the element. you would see that the page doesn't slide. the background image slides. basically the carousel slides in the background.

Comment: try to copy the structure. the general rule is the one I posted above.

Comment: From what I can see on the Hugo website, the content also changes! How is that possible if only the background was sliding?

Comment: '<header class="header">' is on top of the slider '<div class="home-slider ci-slider" data-animationspeed="400" data-slideshowspeed="5000" data-slideshow="1" data-direction="horizontal" data-animation="fade">'

Comment: header is not covering the section of slider that has content and changes.

Comment: z-indexing and fixing the the slider div to the top is the answer is the answ

Comment: On Hugo, how have they got the `.home-slider` div to take up the full page? I can't see it in the CSS! Here is how [mine looks](http://nativeleaf.co.uk/static/index.html).

Comment: @Ciwan  inspect element the "<li>" within "<ul>" in  class="home-slider ci-slider"   ... 'width:100%' no height defined as mentioned in my answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101389/discussion-between-ciwan-and-daniel-purpur).

Comment: @Ciwan I am at work and cannot be chatting I can leave few comments once a while but certainly not chatting. this is a very straight forward thins in CSS I am sure by just copying the structure you will learn. It would be nice to mark my answer as correct as well

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Just wanted to clarify that by `full page` I mean full height and full width. I [already have](http://nativeleaf.co.uk/static/index.html) it at full width, but not sure how they're achieving the full height.

Comment: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/autoHeight.html  have you checked the owel options? there is a auto hieght option. it ajjusts automatically.

Comment: display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
it has a position relative, and display block. remember your images are background images so the width and height of the element must be declared

Comment: Remove the overflow hidden on line 23 style.css 
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
... ignore the previous comment